# How do I remove fields from a Crystal Report in VS?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports, report

I've tried to remove these fields from my report for an hour and I could not figure it out.

Please see this picture:
http://i261.photobucket.com/albums/ii43/Accurim/receipt.jpg?t=1261074404

I want to remove the fields in the gray area, but I cannot click on them.  Does anyone know how to remove those fields?  Thanks!

Comment: Another poor CR person.  Sorry had to!

Comment: haha, tell me about it.  I can't wait till this is working and I can never look at CR again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I got it after going to lunch and messing around again.

It was in *right-click report* -> Design -> Printer Setup
I picked Adobe PDF as my printer and just picked a page as large as possible then my page became wider and I could click on all the extra fields.

I tried this earlier instead selecting a Dell printer and picking a large page, but what I didn't realize was it auto-selected a smaller page size so if anyone runs into this just make sure the page size you selected is actually being used.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why your page is only 2" wide? Maybe you need to make the page wider to select those fields. Sorry I've never used the Visual Studio crystal report designer...

Comment: Thanks for the comment, it inspired me to try all the settings again and I got it! :D